# Error unable to run dnf localinstall *.rpm

Tags: nginx, rhel

I am trying to install Nginx on my rhel 8.7. I am not able to run `dnf localinstall *.rpm` on a **non-internet environment** and it is showing some errors.

I tried check the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory but not sure what to do. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to check your `/etc/yum.repos.d` and check if there are any **repo files** in the directory. If there are, try to edit the **repo files** and change the **gpgcheck=0** and **type** in the terminal:

1. `yum repolist`
2. `yum list`
3. Try to run `dnf localinstall *.rpm` again.

It should work now.